# How to order inline view toolbar icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my authoring of a VS Code extension, I'd like to have "+" icon shown to the right of refresh icon. However, the ordering in the `package.json` does not seem to represent the order rendered. I always get the add icon to the left of refresh icon.

[image]

Here is a snippet of the view definition:

```json
{
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "refresh-jobs",
        "title": "Refresh",
        "icon": {
          "light": "resources/light/refresh.svg",
          "dark": "resources/dark/refresh.svg"
        }
      },
      {
        "command": "add-job",
        "title": "Add",
        "icon": {
          "light": "resources/light/add.svg",
          "dark": "resources/dark/add.svg"
        }
      },
    ],
    ...
    "view/item/context": [
        {
          "command": "refresh-jobs",
          "group": "inline",
          "when": "viewItem == jobgroup"
        },
        {
          "command": "add-job",
          "group": "inline",
          "when": "viewItem == jobgroup"
        },
    ]
}
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: Is it just alphabetical by `title` (or possibly `command`)?  Easy to check.

Comment: I believe it's alpahbetical by one of them. Question is, say that's true, how to override the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this old issue: [Add custom ordering to title menu items.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15596) which suggest doing something like:

> There is way to define the order and I am surprised we haven't
> properly documented that... What you can do is adding an order to the
> group-attribute like so `group: name@number`. In your case
>
> ```
> {    
>  "command": "md-shortcut.toggleBold",
>   "when": "editorLangId == 'markdown'",
>   "group": "2_markdown_1@1"  
> }
> ```

I see it here: [menu example](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#menu-example)  The `@n` syntax is used there to order menu entries but the issue I cited above seems to imply that it will also order icons in a title bar.  Try this:

```
    "view/item/context": [
        {
          "command": "refresh-jobs",
          "group": "inline@1",
          "when": "viewItem == jobgroup"
        },
        {
          "command": "add-job",
          "group": "inline@2",
          "when": "viewItem == jobgroup"
        },
    ]
```

`"group": "inline@1",` note the @1

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Great, I think this particular usage is still not documented unfortunately.